# Modifying a TiKZ tree scheme

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to modify a tree scheme that I found in one example, however I can't get what I am trying to do.

[image]

I would like to add two rectangles below the last one depicted in the figure. From the `$A_{prv}\Delta P$` node should appear the line as in "Q=" giving way to two more options.

Code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {$(\zeta,\Omega)\rightarrow (y,v_y)$}
    child { node {$\dot{\zeta} = \Omega$}}      
    child { node {$\dot{\Omega} = $}}
    child { node {$\dot{P_1} = (B/V)(Q-A\lambda d)$}}
    child { node {$\dot{P_2} = (B/V)(Q-A\lambda d)$}}
    child { node  {Q =}
      child { node {$0$ \hspace{14mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 < F_{pc}$}}
      child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please clearly specify what do you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version 1:** Two sub-nodes of the last node.

Replace

```
  child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}}};
```

by

```
  child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}
           child { node {Child 1 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
           child { node {Child 2 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
        }
      };
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {$(\zeta,\Omega)\rightarrow (y,v_y)$}
    child { node {$\dot{\zeta} = \Omega$}}      
    child { node {$\dot{\Omega} = $}}
    child { node {$\dot{P_1} = (B/V)(Q-A\lambda d)$}}
    child { node {$\dot{P_2} = (B/V)(Q-A\lambda d)$}}
    child { node  {Q =}
      child { node {$0$ \hspace{14mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 < F_{pc}$}}
      child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}
               child { node {Child 1 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
               child { node {Child 2 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
            }
          };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Version 2:** Two more sub-nodes of `Q =`.

Replace

```
  child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}}};
```

by

```
  child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}}
  child { node {Child 1 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
  child { node {Child 2 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
      };
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {$(\zeta,\Omega)\rightarrow (y,v_y)$}
    child { node {$\dot{\zeta} = \Omega$}}      
    child { node {$\dot{\Omega} = $}}
    child { node {$\dot{P_1} = (B/V)(Q-A\lambda d)$}}
    child { node {$\dot{P_2} = (B/V)(Q-A\lambda d)$}}
    child { node  {Q =}
      child { node {$0$ \hspace{14mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 < F_{pc}$}}
      child { node  {$A_{prv}\Delta P$ \hspace{3mm} if: \hspace{3mm} $P_1A_1-P_2A_2 \geq F_{pc}$}}
      child { node {Child 1 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
      child { node {Child 2 of $A_{prv}\Delta P$}}
          };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```